# Overiding homepage template problem. "page__front.tpl.php" won't be loaded

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to overriding the homepage by creating a template file named "page__front.tpl.php"; I placed it under the theme folder where page.tpl.php lives.

After refreshing the site, the homepage still loads "page.tpl.php" instead of "page__front.tpl.php."
The cache and the theme registry are cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template filename should be "page--front.tpl.php"; you should use hyphens, not underscores.